# stream mp4 video with node fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, video, express, ffmpeg, stream

I'm trying to create video stream server and client with node **fluent-ffmpeg**, **express** and **ejs**. And a haven't solve this for a while.
What I want to do is to play video beginning by certain time.
The following codes make it with **Safari browser** on windows but with others it makes a loop of a few seconds or it says

> video format not supported

**server code (run.js)** :

```js
app.get('/video', function(req, res) {

  //define file path,time to seek the beegining and set ffmpeg binary
  var pathToMovie = '../videos/test.mp4';
  var seektime = 100; 
  proc.setFfmpegPath(__dirname + "/ffmpeg/ffmpeg");


  //encoding the video source
  var proc = new ffmpeg({source: pathToMovie})
         .seekInput(seektime)
         .withVideoBitrate(1024)
         .withVideoCodec('libx264')
         .withAspect('16:9')
         .withFps(24)
         .withAudioBitrate('128k')
         .withAudioCodec('libfaac')
         .toFormat('mp4');

  //pipe 
         .pipe(res, {end: true});
});
```

**client code (index.ejs):**

```html
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <video>
      <source src="video/" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
  </body>

</html>
```

Help please. I searched everywhere solution but I didn't find

Comment: Try setting the `Content-Type` header in the response with `res.set('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');`.

Comment: hi! I tried this but still doesn't work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in order to seek within a mp4 or mp3, you need to let the browser know the length of that content.  Try inserting this quick blurb before you make your call to `ffmpeg`.  This should get the size of the video file and you can set the headers in the response accordingly before streaming the data.

**INSERT BEFORE ffmpeg call**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stat = fs.statSync(pathToMovie);
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    'Content-Length': stat.size
});
```